# VNC slow connection on Ubuntu 16.04 in Intel NUC

Tags: networking, 16.04, remote-desktop, vnc

I have Intel NUC and have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. Everything seems to work fine when accessing the NUC to hdmi monitor. I have installed VNC on it and enabled its remote connection. I can connect to it from anywhere I want but the connection looks very slow.

I have checked the network on both the ends and the network is pretty good but don't know why the VNC connections are very slow. Is there any settings which I can enable/disable to improve the connection speed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu default desktop is a bit slow, so I have installed `xfce4` desktop by using command

`sudo apt-get install xfce4`

after this the connection is very stable and fast.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a trusted LAN using the remmina client, then I find that disabling encryption in the vino server greatly improves my speed over 5G WiFi:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep -i vino

$ gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

Then be sure to select the '[ ] Disable encryption' option in the 'Advanced' tab of your client connection.